# html hierarchy changes

Tags: html, css

I changed markup in one page like this,
before change

```
<div class="header-wrapper header">         
   <h1 wicket:id="headerTitle" class="dealer-name">Excellence Holden</h1>
</div>
```

after change

```
 <h1 class="header-wrapper header">         
    <span wicket:id="headerTitle" class="dealer-name">Excellence Holden</span>
 </h1>
```

after changing the mark up the font size of "Excellence Holden" is increasing .It will happen or I am doing something wrong ?

css code:

```
.header-wrapper {
    padding:15px 0;        
}
 .header-wrapper .dealer-name {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the change, the font size set on the inner element, `1.3em`, changes its meaning. The reason is when used in the value of the `font-size` element, the `em` unit denotes the font size of the parent element. Here the parent element is an `h1` element, and the common and recommended browser default is that `h1` element has a font size of `2em`, i.e. twice its parent’s font size.

To override this effect, add the following:

```
h1.header-wrapper { font-size: 1em; }
```

Comment: Thank you . actually I resolved it by doing the same, but now I clearly understood the reason behind it.

Comment: Hi i need some more information on this. how can we calculate this value. for example if it is 1.3 em i changed it to 1 em. if it is 1.6 em etc etc how can we find the exact value ?or if it is in px ?

Comment: @ChowdaryChowdary, it is not clear what you are asking here (and whether it should be posted as a completely new question). There seems to be unnecessary confusion, since you could simply use `h1` for a heading, set `font-size` on it, and if you use `span` inside it, just let it inherit font size from its parent.

Comment: I am sorry, what 
Iam asking is after changing the markup,i just changed the value to 1em and in some places they are using font-size:1.1em. in this case I reset it to 0.85em(i just made a trail here ).How can we find the new value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the font size of the span in css, find the font defined for h1 then apply the same font to the  tag

Comment: I did the same . i didn't changed the css .I used same class for both span and h1. But still for the same font size it is increasing

Answer (score 0):

Because if you do not reset the `font-size` for h1, it automatically is higher than normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that is a CSS related,

usually the new CSS files contains Font (`Size`, `Family`, `weight`) properties for `<h1>` tags.

please check both `h1` and `span` CSS Attributes. you can use the browser inspectors (Chrome Inspect Element) to see the actual attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your styling. When changing HTML like this you need to ensure that the styling is also changed accordingly.

For example:

```
div.header { font-weight:bold; }
div.header h1 { font-size:24px; }
```

The above CSS would be applied to the first HTML snippet, but *not* the second. You'd have to change this to:

```
h1.header { font-weight:bold; }
h1.header span { font-size:24px; }
```

And also ensure that there is no other `h1` or `span` styling that may affect this.